# NextJS - Link - href - ссылка на локальное изображение

Tags: nextjs

Перевел проект на NextJS и столкнулся с проблемой в fancybox галлереи. Здесь необходимо указать ссылку на локальное изображение. Но при указании в свойстве href путь к изображению - получаю [Object object].

```
<Link
  key={img.id}
  data-fancybox="gallery"
  href={img.original}
  style={{ flexBasis: '18%' }}
>
  <Image
    src={img.thumbnail}
    height={140}
    width={185}
    alt={img.description}
 />
</Link>
```

Как правильно указать ссылку на изображение?